# gnuplot error-“no data in file”, “x range invalid”, “bad data line 1”-trying to use virtual machine statistics in gnuplot

Tags: linux, bash, graph, ubuntu-12.04, gnuplot

I have written a script below to output the statistics for vmstat, iostat and sar. They output ok and I am stressing them to check the comparisons. Once they have been run, I have been running gnuplot in an attempt to get the statistics output on graphs. I have installed both gnuplot and dstat on my ubuntu 12.04 server but the graphs are not working. It is giving me several errors which I have mentioned within the title. I finally decided to remove all references to gnuplot from my script and just use gnuplot on the command line calling my files, and it still throws back one of the above error messages. It has been the same on every template I have found online and it is driving me mad. Can someone please solve it? All I want to do is to run the statistics and make graphs from them-it shouldn't be so frustrating.

I have included my script in case it is needed. Is it even possible to use gnuplot within my script so that the user can select the length of time and run a script immediately afterwards? Or should gnuplot be separated into an entirely different bash script? 
I have asked about this before but the quality of the answers was awful.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to get sar statistics#
echo "Enter the number of intervals (seconds) for the sar statistics:"
read int
echo "enter the number of output lines (count) to process:"
read cnt
clear
#set while

    while true; do
    clear
echo "*******************************"
echo "* Choose from the following: *"
echo "*******************************"
echo "* [1] To view process creation statistics *"
echo "* [2] To view I/O and transfer rate statistics *"
echo "* [3] To view paging statistics *"
echo "Press A to quit."
echo "************************"
echo -n "Enter your menu choice [0-15]: "
D=`/bin/date '+%B.%d'`
INT=$int
CNT=$cnt
read mychoice
case $mychoice in
1) echo "process creation statistics";
vmstat $INT $CNT |tee /tmp/sar_proc_stat_$D
echo "This file will be saved to /tmp/sar_pc_stat_$D"
sleep 3 ;;
2) echo "I/O and transfer rate statistics"
iostat $INT $CNT |tee /tmp/sar_IO_TR_stat_$D
echo "This file will be saved to /tmp/sar_IO_TR_stat_$D"
sleep 3 ;;
3) echo "paging statistics"
sar  $INT $CNT |tee /tmp/sar_pag_stat_$D
echo "This file will be saved to /tmp/sar_pag_stat_$D"
sleep 3 ;;
A) #Quit option
    echo You have now quit. Please return to the main menu. 
    exit;;

    *) #Wildcard option
     echo Invalid choice, please make another choice;;

esac
done
```

Comment: If I did not fully misunderstand your problem, it has nothing to do with your script but happens in Gnuplot (or at least this should reveal what the problems with your files are). So, you should be able to give us a minimal non-working example containing some gnuplot command or script and some minimal data file. Furthermore, where have you asked this before?

Comment: You've got NO ANSWERS because your question is ill-posed.  Your bash script is COMPLETELY irrilevant to your question. Please post  (short) examples of `sar_pc_stat_...`, `sar_IO_TR_stat_...` and `sar_pag_stat_...` files, as well as the `gnuplot` commands that you've used and you'll see many answers flooding towards you.

Comment: From a glimpse to what `vmstat`, `iostat` and `sar` commands typically produce, you need some preprocessing before `gnuplot` could be able to plot your data, are you aware of that or do you expect that `gnuplot` does all this stuff on its own?